# addEventListener method with dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am new to `addEventListener` method. I am trying to use `onClick` event on my dynamically created js table to change the cell values, but table vanishes when I put the `addeventlistener` code line inside the function. I am trying to give each cell a dynamic id.and then add an `addeventlistener` method using these lines of code:

```
s.setAttribute('id',"tab"+v);
         document.getElementById("tab"+v).addEventListeners("click",function(){var g=document.getElementById("tab"+v);
         g.innerHTML="changed";},false);

        v++;
```

Can anyone explain to me how can I solve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>table dynamic</title>
<style>
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}

.tableShape{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:centre;
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;

}
.rowShape{height:33%;width:33%;border:1px solid black;}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var i,j,v=1;
var arr=new Array(3);
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
arr[i]=new Array(3);
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
for(j=0;j<3;j++){
arr[i][j]=1;
}}

function tabs(){
   var k,t;
    var m=document.createElement("table");
    m.setAttribute('class',"tableShape");

    for(var  k = 0;k < 3; k++){
    var p=m.insertRow(k);
       for( var t = 0;t < 3; t++){
         var s=p.insertCell(t);
         s.setAttribute('class',"rowShape");
        s.innerHTML+=arr[k][t];
    s.setAttribute('id',"tab"+v);
         document.getElementById("tab"+v).addEventListeners("click",function(){var g=document.getElementById("tab"+v);
         g.innerHTML="changed";},false);

        v++;
         }
         }
         document.body.appendChild(m);
    }


    window.onLoad=tabs();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be aware of the fact, that the callback function you give as parameter to addEventListener() is first evaluated when the event happened - so it then takes the value of "v".
What you need is a local copy of v's value - you can achieve this by a closure, like this:

```
s.setAttribute('id', "tab" + v);
document.getElementById("tab" + v).addEventListeners("click", (function(val) {
        return function() {
            var g = document.getElementById("tab" + val);
            g.innerHTML = "changed";
        };
        })(v), false);

    v++;
```

You can find a simple example closure here: http://jsfiddle.net/9JAG2/

Cheers

Florian